# Inserting rowtype record, which is passed as a parameter in PL/SQL in Oracle. How can I achieve this?

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowtype

I am trying to achieve below scenario. How can I achieve below insert given below?

```
declare
v_insSql varchar2(1000);
v_table_name varchar2(50):='TEMP_TBL';
v_row Table_T1%ROWTYPE;
/* Just to avoid everyone's confusion, both table_t1 and temp_tbl are of same structure */

BEGIN
SELECT * INTO v_row FROM Table_T1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
v_insSql:= 'INSERT INTO '||v_table_name||' VALUES :l_row';
/* table_name will always be passed as variable */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insSql using v_row;
END;
```

Can someone pls help?

Comment: Any help on this using dynamic SQL instead of if-else block?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dynamic SQL; just use a normal SQL insert:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_insSql varchar2(1000);
  v_table_name varchar2(50):='TEMP_TBL';
  v_row Table_T1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_row FROM Table_T1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
  INSERT INTO temp_tbl VALUES v_row;
END;
/
```

So, for some sample tables/data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_t1 ( a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER );
INSERT INTO table_t1 ( a, b, c ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 );
CREATE TABLE temp_tbl AS SELECT * FROM table_t1 WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM temp_tbl;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>  A |  B |  C
> -: | -: | -:
>  1 |  2 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ebbaccfa0852c860474628bfce6d8ee)*

---

If you want to have dynamic table names then white-list the tables so you don't need to use dynamic SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_insSql varchar2(1000);
  v_table_name varchar2(50):='TEMP_TBL';
  v_row Table_T1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_row FROM Table_T1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
  IF v_table_name = 'TEMP_TBL' THEN
    INSERT INTO temp_tbl VALUES v_row;
  ELSIF v_table_name = 'TABLE_T1' THEN
    INSERT INTO table_t1 VALUES v_row;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fddf28137336cf92018621726a1e4f8f)*

Comment: thanks for your reply.. if I don't want to use if-else block, can't it be done using dynamic sql only?

Comment: @VaibhavGupta I have not found a way to use `%ROWTYPE` with dynamic SQL; it always seems to throw `ORA-00902: invalid datatype` exceptions. Not saying that there isn't a way to do it but it isn't obvious that it will work and the documentation for this is very sparse. If you want a full answer then you would be best asking the question direct to Oracle.

Comment: Exactly, I am also getting the same error. Since there are lot many tables, if-else block won't work over here in my case. Anyways, thanks a bunch for this too!

Answer (score 0):

You can get what your after but with the intermediate step of defining and filling a %rowtype variable. Since the source table (Table_T1) and the target table (Temp_Tbl) must have identical structure you insert directly for select.

```
declare                                                                
   k_sql_stmt   constant varchar2(100) := 'insert into <table_name> select * from table_t1 where rownum=1';
   l_sql_stmt   varchar2(100);
   l_table_name varchar2(30) := 'temp_tbl'; 
begin 
   l_sql_stmt := replace(k_sql_stmt,'<table_name>',l_table_name); 
   dbms_output.put_line ('Run Statement==> ''' || l_sql_stmt || '''');
   execute immediate l_sql_stmt;  
end ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach.. Is there any way I can return ROWID for the above inserted SINGLE row? Considering there can be too many records in the temp_tbl.. Appreciate your help!